# move_uploaded_filefailed to open stream: Invalid argument in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting a problem in following code:

```
$file_name = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.') . gettimeofday()['usec']; 
$uploaddir = 'customerupload/';
$file = basename($_FILES['profile_photo']['name']);
$newname = $file_name . $file;
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $newname;    

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['profile_photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) 
{
   //my Logic
}
```

The error is:

[image]

What can be the cause?

Comment: Try change - `date('Y-m-d H:i:s.')` - to - `date('Y-m-d H-i-s.')` - colon `:` may not be allowed and is causing the error.

Comment: it's working thanks @– Mr. Blue

Answer (score 0):

Try to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR for correct path syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php

And do not trust filenames coming from forms in this simple way.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name = date('Y-m-d H-i-s.') . gettimeofday()['usec'];
```

i used : but i have replaced it by - so its working